# GTK+: what does the gtk_ui_manager_add_ui_from_resource function do?

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I see the function `gtk_ui_manager_add_ui_from_resource` used in several places, but can't find any documentation for it in [GTK+ 3 Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/index.html). What does this function do?

I guess it should be similar to that of [gtk_ui_manager_add_ui_from_file](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkUIManager.html#gtk-ui-manager-add-ui-from-file), but what does "resource" refers to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, googling I found [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-January/msg06991.html), it still is of the gnome webpage.

It says

> This is a helper function to easily add ui from resource files.

Indeed, they are very similar:

```
guint gtk_ui_manager_add_ui_from_file    (GtkUIManager *manager, 
                                          const gchar *filename,
                                          GError **error);

guint gtk_ui_manager_add_ui_from_resource(GtkUIManager *manager,
                                          const gchar *resource_path,
                                          GError **error);
```

The resource is described as:

> resource_path: the resource path of the file to parse

So they would only differ in the way the file is obtained.

Hope it helps...